How to get rid of unwanted bone in Auto rig pro?
I use Auto Rig Pro, I select head rig from "add limb" rid of everything unnecessary bones for my character.

All but only eyes

then I click the match to rig

some of the rig  eyelid is still there cause my character doesn't have any eyelids and weird
muti-bones


Please add pictures or videos as an example.

Switch to Edit mode, select them and press X?
